# Flex charting - Fixing the background grid and multi-line plotting

Tags: apache-flex, graph, charts, actionscript

I have two requirements for a flex charting component:

1. The grid lines should always remain fixed to a scaling I define using an array of data. Something like a graph paper sheet.
2. Plot multiple line series data over this grid.

How does one get complete control over the background grid lines? I have tried a combination of annotation elements and setting the linechart background elements. If I get the grid right, I can't plot over it (Probably due to the scale). Can anyone share how would one go about designing a graphpaper like interface for linecharts in flex/actionscript?